# Defining Storable for Recursive Data Structure Involving Vectors

Tags: haskell, vector, storable

I have a data structure of the form below (V is Data.Storable.Vector):

```
data Elems = I {-# UNPACK #-} !GHC.Int.Int32
             | S {-# UNPACK #-} !GHC.Int.Int32 {-# UNPACK #-} !(Ptr CChar)
             | T {-# UNPACK #-} !(V.Vector Elems)
                deriving (Show)
```

I first wrote a custom storable definition for non-recursive form (i.e., without `T` constructor). Then, I tried to add custom peek and poke definition for `T` using `ForeignPtr` and `length` information from `Vector` (code is below). The GHC compiler complains about `Storable` instance not being defined for `ForeignPtr Elems` type. My question is if it is possible to store ptr to Vector in Storable definition, without being forced to write Storable instance definition for ForeignPtr.

From [Haddocs](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/haskell2010-1.1.0.0/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html) documentation, ForeignPtr seems to be just a Ptr with a Finalizer assigned to it:

> The essential difference between ForeignPtrs and vanilla memory
>   references of type Ptr a is that the former may be associated with
>   finalizers.

I don't want to work around the issue by using `Ptr` instead of `ForeignPtr`, because of issues of finalizing it. So, I prefer storing location of ForeignPtr (through `Ptr (ForeignPtr a)`) so that GHC garbage collector knows about the reference to it. But, that approach would force me to define a `Storable instance` (because of constraint `(Storable a) => Ptr a` which makes sense).

Is there a way to store and retrieve ptr to a Vector in Storable, without defining Storable instance for ForeignPtr? If there isn't, then writing the Storable definition of ForeignPtr is a must. In that case, what would it look like? My guess is it will just store a Ptr to ForeignPtr.

The full code below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as V
import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types (CChar)
import Foreign.Marshal.Array (lengthArray0)
import GHC.Int

data Elems = I {-# UNPACK #-} !GHC.Int.Int32
             | S {-# UNPACK #-} !GHC.Int.Int32 {-# UNPACK #-} !(Ptr CChar)
             | T {-# UNPACK #-} !(V.Vector Elems)
                deriving (Show)

instance Storable Elems where
  sizeOf _ = sizeOf (undefined :: Word8) + sizeOf (undefined :: Int32) + sizeOf (undefined :: Ptr CChar)
  alignment _ = 4

  {-# INLINE peek #-}
  peek p = do
      let p1 = (castPtr p::Ptr Word8) `plusPtr` 1 -- get pointer to start of the element. First byte is type of element
      t <- peek (castPtr p::Ptr Word8)
      case t of
        1 -> do 
          x <- peek (castPtr p1 :: Ptr GHC.Int.Int32) 
          return (I x)
        2 -> do 
          x <- peek (castPtr p1 :: Ptr GHC.Int.Int32) 
          y <- peek (castPtr (p1 `plusPtr` 4) :: Ptr (Ptr CChar)) -- increment pointer by 4 bytes first
          return (S x y)
        _ -> do
          x <- peek (castPtr p1 :: Ptr Int)
          y <- peek (castPtr (p1 `plusPtr` 8) :: Ptr (ForeignPtr Elems)) 
          return (T (V.unsafeFromForeignPtr y 0 x)) -- return vector

  {-# INLINE poke #-}
  poke p x = case x of
      I a -> do
        poke (castPtr p :: Ptr Word8) 1  
        poke (castPtr p1) a
      S a b -> do
        poke (castPtr p :: Ptr Word8) 2
        poke (castPtr p1) a
        poke (castPtr (p1 `plusPtr` 4)) b -- increment pointer by 4 bytes first
      T x -> do
        poke (castPtr p :: Ptr Word8) 3
        let (fp,_,n) = V.unsafeToForeignPtr x
        poke (castPtr p1) n
        poke (castPtr (p1 `plusPtr` 8)) fp

      where  p1 = (castPtr p :: Ptr Word8) `plusPtr` 1 -- get pointer to start of the element. First byte is type of element
```

Comment: You might want to consider using `-funbox-strict-fields` rather than putting `{-# UNPACK #-}` pragmas on every field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ForeignPtr`s cannot be made `Storable`, because their implementation demands a way to associate one or many finalizer pointers to a raw pointer, and this association is runtime-dependent. To make the `ForeignPtr` storable, you need to store the associated `Ptr` (which is easy) and the array of associated finalizers (which is impossible, since the finalizers are runtime-internal, and might bind to the GC of the GHC runtime).

This is not the problem that needs to be solved here, though.

The problem is that there's no reasonable way to make something that contains a `Vector` into something `Storable`. A `Vector` demands **managed** memory for its contents (The definition of `Storable.Vector` is `data Vector a = Vector Int (ForeignPtr a)` plus some strictness annotations), but the whole purpose of `Storable` is to store some value into **unmanaged** memory. Further, a `Vector` uses **different amounts** of memory depending on its length, but `Storable` data structures must use a **constant** amount of memory.

You need to rethink what your data structure is trying to model. Do you really need to store a `Vector` like this? Remember that you are storing a `Vector` of `Elems`, meaning that you can have a value `T` that contains a `Vector` that contains a `T` that contains a `Vector` that contains a `T`, etc.

I think that you might be trying to model the following data structure instead, but I might be wrong:

```
data Elems = OneElem Elem | ManyElems (Vector Elem)

data Elem
    = I !GHC.Int.Int32
    | S !GHC.Int.Int32 !(Ptr CChar)
```

If you really need the recursive data structure that you described, try to implement this instead:

```
data Elems
    = I !GHC.Int.Int32
    | S !GHC.Int.Int32 !(Ptr CChar)
    | T !GHC.Int.Int32 !(Ptr Elems)
```

A pointer to some `Elems` uses **constant** memory, and can point to **unmanaged** memory, so you can create storable instances for it.

Comment: thanks for thorough post. I am trying to model the recursive vectors - the reason it turns out that way is because of mixed vectors (for example Vector (Vector of chars, Vector of Ints, Vector of Floats,...)) I have to deal with when interacting with data in real-world. I simplified my example. It will be more like: data Elems = I !Int32 | IV !(Vector Int32) |...| T !(Vector Elems). If I am not mistaken, your second definition of Elems would still be unable to handle it. But, I got some ideas from your first definition. Working on them now